# Please list Question & Answer forum for robot developer?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. http://anwsers.ros.org
2. http://answers.opencv.org/questions/
3. http://answers.gazebosim.org
4. 

...

anyone knows ???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200302/please-list-question-&-answer-forum-for-robot-developer-!/) by [roschina](https://answers.ros.org/users/20157/roschina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- For general robotics Q&A, relatively new site http://robotics.stackexchange.com/ might be the best (that said, if you aksing for broader purpose than just ROS, you should ask there, not here).
- Followings are more general forums (i.e. not Q&A per se) but there seem to be very skilled hobbyists and professionals:
- HBRobotics (Homebrew Robotics Club) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hbrobotics
- DPRG (Dallas Personal Robotics Group) http://www.dprg.org/

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1